# Grid graph traversal

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose I have an nxn grid graph, like this one:

[image]

Starting at a node in the bottom left corner (or any corner), how can I traverse this graph so that I go through all edges and return the the starting point, but minimize the number of times I go through an edge more than once?

I tried doing it by trial and error, and the least number of re-crossings I got was 6. I'm wondering if there is another way to do it, and get a lesser number of re-crossings.

Comment: Check out [Eulerian Circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) for a good starting point.

Comment: You are looking for a Eulerian Cycle. The cereal point is the in/out-degrees of the vertices. Check Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path

Comment: But a connected graph can have a Eulerian circuit iff all its vertices have an even degree, right? In this grid graph, the "side" vertices (those on the side of the square) have degree 3, so it cannot have an Eulerian circuit, is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, there is none, but it gives an easy solution with 4 re-crossings

Comment: As Stefan noted, where can you add 4 edges/recrossings to make all degrees even?

Comment: I see, so the way to go about it is to 'add' edges to make the odd degrees even? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution would be to use each edge exactly once. This would be called an "Euler tour". Such a tour exists if and only if

1. The graph is connected (which a grid always is).
2. Every vertex has an even degree (so it is possible to enter and leave that vertex the same number of times).

In case of a grid-graph, the vertices have degree 2 (on the corner), 3 (on the sides), or 4 (all interior points). So in order to do only minimal extra work, you only want to add new edges (or more precisely double up existing edges) for the side-vertices, of which there are $2(n+m-4)$.

So the answer is that you have to add $n+m-4$ additional edges. If $n$ and $m$ are even, it is easy to do this by doubling up existing edges on the side.